# Pandas groupby expanding optimization of syntax

Tags: python, pandas

I am using the data from the example shown here:
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html.  Go to the subheading:  New syntax to window and resample operations

At the command prompt, the new syntax works as shown in the pandas documentation.  But I want to add a new column with the expanded data to the existing dataframe, as would be done in a saved program.

Before a syntax upgrade to the groupby expanding code, I was able to use the following single line code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1] * 10 + [5] * 10, 'B': np.arange(20)})
df['Sum of B'] = df.groupby('A')['B'].transform(lambda x: pd.expanding_sum(x))
```

This gives the expected results, but also gives an 'expanding_sum is deprecated' message.  Expected results are:

```
    A   B  Sum of B
0   1   0         0
1   1   1         1
2   1   2         3
3   1   3         6
4   1   4        10
5   1   5        15
6   1   6        21
7   1   7        28
8   1   8        36
9   1   9        45
10  5  10        10
11  5  11        21
12  5  12        33
13  5  13        46
14  5  14        60
15  5  15        75
16  5  16        91
17  5  17       108
18  5  18       126
19  5  19       145
```

I want to use the new syntax to replace the deprecated syntax.  If I try the new syntax, I get the error message:

```
df['Sum of B'] = df.groupby('A').expanding().B.sum()

TypeError: incompatible index of inserted column with frame index
```

I did some searching on here, and saw something that might have helped, but it gave me a different message:

```
df['Sum of B'] = df.groupby('A').expanding().B.sum().reset_index(level = 0)

ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 2, placement implies 1
```

The only way I can get it to work is to assign the result to a temporary df, then merge the temporary df into the original df:

```
temp_df = df.groupby('A').expanding().B.sum().reset_index(level = 0).rename(columns = {'B' : 'Sum of B'})
new_df = pd.merge(df, temp_df, on = 'A', left_index = True, right_index = True)
print (new_df)
```

This code gives the expected results as shown above.

I've tried different variations using transform as well, but have not been able to come up with coding this in one line as I did before the deprecation.  Is there a single line syntax that will work?  Thanks.

Comment: `df['Sum of B'] = df.groupby('A').cumsum()`

Comment: @AChampion: if that's meant to be an answer, add it as an answer.

Comment: Thank you, this works.  I am not sure if I have to ask a new question for this one, but in the above example, substitute 'rolling' for 'expanding' and 'mean' for 'sum'.  Is there a 'rollmean' equivalent for cumsum?  If not, my question remains valid for 'rolling' and 'mean'.  If I have to ask a new question, I will.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need a cumsum:

```
df.groupby('A')['B'].cumsum()
```

Comment: Thanks @AChampion. Have updated answer and kept column 'B' there in case there are more columns in the DF.

Answer (score 0):

## TL;DR

```
df['Sum of B'] = df.groupby('A')['B'].transform(lambda x: x.expanding().sum())
```

## Explanation

We start from the offending line:

```
df.groupby('A')['B'].transform(lambda x: pd.expanding_sum(x))
```

Let's read carefully the warning you mentioned:

> FutureWarning: pd.expanding_sum is deprecated for Series and will be
>   removed in a future version, replace with 
>     Series.expanding(min_periods=1).sum()

After reading [Pandas 0.17.0: pandas.expanding_sum](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.expanding_sum.html) it becomes clear that the `Series` the warning is talking about is the first parameter of the `pd.expanding_sum`. I.e. in our case it is `x`.

Now we apply the code transformation suggested in the warning. So `pd.expanding_sum(x)` becomes `x.expanding(min_periods=1).sum()`.

According to [Pandas 0.22.0: pandas.Series.expanding](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.expanding.html) `min_periods` has a default value of `1` so in your case it can be omitted altogether, hence the final result.